# Jersey-server Maven - Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: java, maven, jersey

It looks like the Jersey server has moved to glassfish, but I changed to use correct GAV values and yet I am not having any luck! A simple Jersey helloworld REST project wont build ! Here is my maven dependencies relevant to Jersey

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.xxxxxxx >----------------------
[INFO] Building xxxxxxx Server 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-servlet/2.25/jersey-container-servlet-2.25.pom
Downloading from central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/core/jersey-server/2.25/jersey-server-2.25.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.197 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-25T13:41:38-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project restserver: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxxxxxx:restserver:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.glassfish.jersey.co
ntainers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.25: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.25: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:pom:2.25 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/containers/jersey-container-serv
let/2.25/jersey-container-servlet-2.25.pom with status code 501 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: try switching protocol for `repo1.maven.org/maven2` from `http` to `https`

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer my own question, just so this helps someone and it is easily noticeable.

This has to be the smallest answer - append 's' to http in settings.xml. Not sure how my other projects were building.

Just out of curiosity, after a successful build, I removed the 's' and rebuilt the project without any changes and it starts to pass. It may have cached the binaries in my local repo... and then eventually started failing after a while, so put it back!

Comment: I beleive the reason is maven's default update policy `daily` - so after you successfully built your project using proper access protocol for this repository - the dependencies were cached in your local maven repository so for the following builds during the day the cached dependencies from local repo were used regardless of repo adress you set. Then, after a day passed, maven tried to check the repository for updates and faced the same problem again because the repository does not support `http`

Comment: @Dornaut Absolutely, correct! I checked my "updatePolicy" settings in my settings.xml and it was non-existant for snapshots. Default is daily according to: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-settings/settings.html. Thanks